# Duda sobre POO - campos de clase Java

Tags: java

La duda es que en un ejemplo que el profesor pone para explicar el tema de los getter y setter declara una clase con las siguientes variables:

```
 private int ruedas;

 private int largo;

 private int ancho;

 private int motor;

 private int pesoInicial;

 private int pesoFinal;

 private String color;

 private boolean asientosDeCuero,climatizador ;
```

Mi pregunta es  que:

> ¿si sería incorrecto declarar las variables asientos de cuero y climatizador?

Porque en el ejemplo que hace el profesor  da la opción de que con un método de  un objeto de tipo coche el objeto tenga climatizador o no.

¿No sería incorrecto declarar una variable de clase que el objeto no siempre va a utilizar ?

Comment: Y si no la declaras, cuando la necesites, como haces? y pensalo de otra forma.. si tiene es true, y si no tiee es false.. entonces siempre tiene informacion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es incorrecto declarar clases con atributos que puedan estar a null. El objecto que instancies podría tener o no dicho valor.
Piensa en una clase coche que tiene el atributo matrícula. El coche existe antes de que se le asigne su matrícula correspondiente.
Por otro lado, las propiedades del tipo primitvo boolean siempre tienen valor. Su valor por defecto es false.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Entiendo que no siempre los atributos tienen que tener un valor iniciado siempre ¿No?.

Comment: Exactamente @Carlos